# How to sort In Elasticsearch by parent and nested fields at the same time?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested

I need to sort in Elasticsearch by parent and nested fields at the same time. My data are like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "rank": 8,
        "price": 12.45,
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": "777",
                "rank": 12,
                "price": 45.75
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "rank": 35,
        "price": 5.95,
        "offers": null
    }
]
```

I need to sort the results on `rank` in such a manner that when the `offers` are not `null` I should take nested `offers.rank` value, otherwise I should take the parent `rank` value.
I tried this script, but it did not work:

```
    "sort": [
        {
            "_script": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "doc['offers'].size()==0 ? doc['rank'].value : doc['offers.rank'].value",
                    "lang": "painless"
                },
                "type": "number",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
```

It did not work probably because `offers.rank` is from a nested `offers` object, which is not accessible. But I do not understand how to handle it - if I add a nested condition for the whole script, then my parent value `doc['rank'].value` will not be accessible anymore. It is possible to sort here by parent and nested fields at the same time?

Comment: If the nest field 'offers' contains multiple offers then which value to consider while sorting the documents?

Comment: Just the first for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in assuming that the parent rank would not be accessible. Now, you could either

1. create 2 separate sort 'objects', one for the parent, one for the nested offers, and then sum the results up using the [sort mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_sort_mode_option) or
2. iterate on the `_source` instead:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
          if (params._source.offers instanceof ArrayList
              && params._source.offers.length > 0) {
            return params._source['offers'][0].rank;
          }
          return params._source.rank
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that since we're working with an 'offers' `ArrayList` here, you'll need some sort of mechanism to pick a rank. That's up to you -- I've simply accessed the first offer's rank and you may want to sort the array list & pick the highest one...

Here's a one-liner if that's what you prefer:

```
params._source.offers instanceof ArrayList && params._source.offers.length > 0 ? params._source['offers'][0].rank : params._source.rank
```

Comment: Thank you @joe. I tried the second solution and it works. Though at the beginning of the condition we need to add an extra condition `params._source.offers != null` otherwise the request fails with `...,"lang":"painless","caus
ed_by":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}`. This is because `offers` can be `null`.

Comment: It is very good to know that the `solution #2` technically exists and we can access `parent` and `nested` fields in one script! Though I found in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-source that `Accessing the _source field is much slower than using doc-values.` So I need to test the performance of `solution #2` to understand if it is fast enough for my task. If the performance will not be ok, I will try the `solution #1`.

Comment: Sounds good. It all depends on the index size and how docs you're sorting (since the sorting action happens after query resolution.)

Comment: can `params._source['offers'][0].rank` be written in the form of `params._source.offers[0].rank`? Or the latter form is not correct and only the first one should be used?

Comment: The `_source` is of type `SourceLookup` which implements 
`HashMap` so both are acceptable -- https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.0.0/org/elasticsearch/search/lookup/SourceLookup.html