# Elasticsearch script: can a nested date be accessed directly as a date object?

Tags: sorting, datetime, elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-painless

In my ES data, there are `nested` and `parent` date fields. I need to use these dates in one ES painless script. It is easy to operate with the `parent` date as it is treated as a `time object`. For example, to transform `parent` dates `doc['validFrom']` to UNIX-time number I just use:

```
doc['validFrom'].value.millis
```

But it is a different case for operating with `nested` dates like `params._source['offers'][0].validFrom`. These dates are returned as a `String`, not `date`. So I have to parse them to `date` object manually:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(params._source['offers'][0].validFrom), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

This manual date parsing brings extra complexity to the script. It seems to me that it is also not good for performance. Can a `nested date field` be accessed as a `date object` in elasticsearch script directly without parsing from String?

P.S
Data example:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "rank": 8,
        "validFrom": "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": "777",
                "rank": 12,
                "validFrom": "2020-07-06T00:00:00"  // !!! should take the date from here
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "rank": 35,
        "validFrom": "2019-05-03T00:00:00"  // !!! should take the date from here as offers are null
        "offers": null
    }
]
```

My Script

```
    "sort": [
        {
            "_script": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "params._source.offers != null ? ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse(params._source['offers'][0].validFrom), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli() : doc['validFrom'].value.millis",
                    "lang": "painless"
                },
                "type": "number",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63939356/8160318).*

The topic here is differentiating between [`doc_values`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals) and [`_source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-source) fields.

Since `doc_values` do return primitive types, you're able to access `.millis` on the date field. But `_source` itself is a JSON-ish, non-analyzed map-of-maps so you only get what was originally ingested, unfortunately.

When you're having trouble w/ the performance, I'd recommend extracting the nested `validFrom` to the top level and call it, say, `validFromOverride`. Your sort script logic complexity will then significantly reduce.

Mappings & doc structure don't need to be immutable.